# what is the use of entitlement and how it can be created?

Tags: iphone, entitlements

I have created a small app which I have not used any `.entitlement` file for running in both simulator and device. Its working fine too...But I don't know where this `.entitlement` file is used and how it can be created.Is it important for the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entitlements are special rights with which an application can gain additional privileges and access to certain functions of the system, such as access to the keychain (`keychain-access-groups` entitlement), launching applications just like SpringBoard does (`com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement), and so on.

An `Entitlements.xml` file is used when codesigning an application, both by the official `codesign_allocate` tool that comes with Xcode and the developer tools, and by the `ldid` utility that can be used for fake codesigning on jailbroken devices. Essentially, it's a property list file which contains one or more of these entitlements and whose contents will be **merged into the executable** during the codesigning process. When the OS attempts to run the application, and it looks for the signature of the binary, it finds the now-hardcoded entitlements file, and instructs the sandbox daemon to lift certain bans of privileges accoring to the contents of that file.

Here are [all documented entitlements](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html) for iOS, other undocumented ones can also be found by looking at some excutable files in iOS.